# Interceptar SQL´s em um custom JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, banco-de-dados

É possível criar uma implementação customizada baseada em **JDBC** para interceptar todos os sql´s executados na aplicação?

Não encontrei nada muito concreto sobre isso no Google, fiz um teste simples apenas herdando a interface do driver que queria e com isso fiz a conexão com o banco e as querys executam perfeitamente mas ainda não descobri como interceptar o que foi executado, se alguém tiver alguma ideia ou exemplo que possa a ajudar a decifrar o enigma, ou qual o melhor caminho pra isso, ou se é impossível.

Segue um exemplo da interface simples:

```
package br.com.jdbc;
import org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FirebirdDriver;

public interface FRDriver extends FirebirdDriver {


}
```

Arquivo para teste:

```
package br.com.jdbc;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBConnection;

public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("br.com.jdbc.FRDriver");
        System.out.println("Connecting to database...");

        FBConnection conn = (FBConnection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost:BANCOTESTE?encoding=WIN1252","SYSDBA","masterkey");
        System.out.println("CONEXAO OK");
        conn.close();
        System.out.println("CONEXAO ENCERRADA");
    }
}
```

Comment: Não, na verdade a conexão usa a interface `FRDriver ` que seria o driver herdado do firebird.

Comment: O projeto é java web? se for dá pra utilizar Interceptors, existem várias formas, seja com spring, cdi, etc... esse link pode te ajudar: http://www.devmedia.com.br/trabalhando-com-o-design-pattern-interceptor-no-java-ee/32842

Comment: @Geferson vou dar uma olhada no link pra ver se abre alguma ideia aqui o projeto seria em web sim com spring.

Comment: Aqui tem alguns exemplos de interceptors com spring mvc, acho que deve te ajudar: http://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-mvc/spring-handlerinterceptor-annotation-example-webmvcconfigureradapter

Comment: @Geferson o que eu estou precisando é mais parecido com isto http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0602.html, mas sem uma biblioteca externa, não sei se apenas o interceptor seria capaz. Mas de toda forma vou tentar.

Comment: Qual seria o seu objetivo exatamente? gerar log das sql e salvá-las?

Comment: A principio seria isso, mas se der tudo certo executar os inserts, delete e updates em um outro banco.

Comment: Com o cdi(spring deve ter também), eu usava um @AroundInvoke para interceptar os métodos que faziam alguma coisa no banco, e injetava um transação nele, o funcionamento desse caso acho que resolveria seu problema. o resto seria implementação do interceptor.